# What is the life cycle of connections in a pool if Min Pool Size is set?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, sqlconnection, max-pool-size

I understand that if Min Pool Size is set in a SQL Database connection string, there will always be that many active connections (at least) in the pool at all times.  My question is this:  Will these always be the same connections or does the pool just ensure that there are that minimum amount of connections and they are always refreshed?  For instance, if I set the Min Pool Size to 2, will the same 2 connections be used over and over again or will the pool occasionally refresh with a different set of 2 active connections?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those same 2 connections will be used over and over again until the underlying SQL Server connection is severed.  See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information.